# Where does the base come from in a subsequence count?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-foundations

If sequence `X` has `m` symbols, then `X` has 2<sup>m</sup> possible subsequences.

Where does the base (`2`) come from?

The origin of this question is the following paragraph:

> We are given two ordered sequences of symbols, and we wish to find a longest common subsequence of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> A subsequence of $X$ is just $X$ with some (or possibly all
>   or none) of its elements removed. For example, one subsequence of `A; B; C; D; E; F; G` would be `B; C; E; G`.
>
> The length of a longest
>   common subsequence of $X$ and $Y$ gives one measure of how similar these
>   two sequences are. For example, if the two sequences are base pairs in
>   DNA strands, then we might consider them similar if they have a long
>   common subsequence.
>
> If $X$ has $m$ symbols and $Y$ has $n$ symbols, then $X$ and
>   $Y$ have $2^m$ and $2^n$ possible subsequences 
>   respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a subsequence $Y$ of $X$ as a characteristic vector $\chi_Y$  that has $m$ elements, one per element of $X$. The $i$-th element of $\chi_Y$ is $1$ if the $i$-th element of $X$ is also in $Y$ and $0$ otherwise.

It is easy to see that this is a bijection: every subsequence $Y$ has a distinct characteristic vector $\chi_Y$, and every characteristic vector $\chi_Y$ is associated to a distinct sequence $Y$.

This means that the number of subsequences $Y$ is equal to the number of vectors $\chi_Y$. Since each vector $\chi_Y$ has $m$ elements, each of which can have one of $2$ possible values, this number is $2^m$.

A concrete example of a sequence $X$, a subsequence $Y$, and its characteristic vector $\chi_Y$ is the following:

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you. Please can you help me understand why each element can only have one of two possible values?

Comment: By definition of $\chi_Y$. Each element of $\chi_Y$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thank you! .....